# Compilation error while playing around with Stock Android (Froyo)?

Tags: android, build, compilation, android-source

I am trying to compile Android (Froyo) from the source for my Nexus One. I pretty much followed all instructions from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=899674).

Though the instructions are for Gingerbread, I don't really see much of a difference for Froyo. After I do a "make -j4", the following error is thrown:

```
Install: out/target/product/passion/system/lib/libmedia.so
target SharedLib: libstagefright_foundation (out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_foundation_intermediates/LINKED/libstagefright_foundation.so)
target SharedLib: libstagefright_color_conversion (out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_color_conversion_intermediates/LINKED/libstagefright_color_conversion.so)
target SharedLib: libaudio (out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudio_intermediates/LINKED/libaudio.so)
target SharedLib: libaudiopolicy (out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libaudiopolicy_intermediates/LINKED/libaudiopolicy.so)
target SharedLib: libcameraservice (out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/LINKED/libcameraservice.so)
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/CameraService.o: in function android::CameraService::getCameraInfo(int, android::CameraInfo*):frameworks/base/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp:109: error: undefined reference to 'HAL_getCameraInfo'
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/CameraService.o: in function android::CameraService::CameraService():frameworks/base/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp:75: error: undefined reference to 'HAL_getNumberOfCameras'
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/CameraService.o: in function android::CameraService::CameraService():frameworks/base/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp:75: error: undefined reference to 'HAL_getNumberOfCameras'
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/CameraService.o: in function android::CameraService::connect(android::sp<android::ICameraClient> const&, int):frameworks/base/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp:148: error: undefined reference to 'HAL_openCameraHardware'
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/CameraService.o: in function android::CameraService::connect(android::sp<android::ICameraClient> const&, int):frameworks/base/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.cpp:154: error: undefined reference to 'HAL_getCameraInfo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/passion/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcameraservice_intermediates/LINKED/libcameraservice.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: cts/tools/dx-tests/src/dxc/junit/opcodes/invokeinterface/jm/T_invokeinterface_1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
compiling all jasmin (*.j)
compiling all .cfh files into .class files
generating Main_*.java files reading from cts/tools/dx-tests writing to out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/dx-tests_intermediates/mainfiles
using java src:cts/tools/dx-tests/src
Collecting all junit tests...

Time: 0.025

OK (0 tests)
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The function was named `getCameraInfo()` in Froyo but was changed to `HAL_getCameraInfo()` in Gingerbread. Therefore the dynamic library, `libcamera.so` extracted from a Froyo machine won't work in a Gingerbread build.

I'm not sure if you are able to bypass this…